# XCode 4.4 issue: 'mach_debug/mach_debug_types.h' file not found

Tags: macos, xcode4

After installing 4.4, I tried building a current project, and get the error: Lexical or preprocessor issue 'mach_debug/mach_debug_types.h' file not found.  It then shows me an include in the file MacOSX10.8/user/include/mach/host_priv.h.  I get the same error regardless of whether i select 10.7 or 10.8 as the target os.  I can't find the file (or the mach_debug directory) on my machine.

Any ideas?

Comment: XCode 4.4, I believe has not been publicly released, therefore under NDA. You should post your question on Apple's developer forums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it just copying folder ../MacOSX10.7/user/include/mach_debug to ../MacOSX10.8/user/include/

Comment: Thanks.  I did the same thing earlier today, but didn't get around to posting it.

Comment: That's a nasty workaround though.  I wouldn't modify system frameworks if you can help it.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to change your Base SDK in the Build Settings section of your current target from Mac OS X 10.8 to Mac OS X 10.7, then recompile, it should work.